# Elasticsearch perform snapshot incrementally

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, snapshot

I have created a snapshot in AWS S3 and I am trying to update the same snapshot every day. Is it possible to do in Elasticsearch cloud-aws plugin ? Tried running the same create snapshot link but it doesn't updates the existing snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is incremental by default.
Which means that you create a repository.
Then create a snapshot to this repo. This one is a full backup.
Then create a new snapshot to the same repo. This one is incremental.

Comment: Thank you ! I have another doubt like, If I have huge data to perform snapshot is there a way to do it in parallel with multiple threads ? Please provide a way in which we could do this ?

Comment: Well. I believe it's already done in parallel. I mean one backup by shard. So if you have multiple shards it's done in parallel. I don't think snapshot/restore itself uses parallelism but I did not look at the code recently.

Comment: If I have 4 to 5 nodes then when I perform file system backup. How this will actually store the snapshot. Will it store in all the nodes are only in a specific node ?

Comment: It is stored on the FileSystem you defined in the repository as the repository type. It can be NFS, S3, Google Storage, Azure...

Comment: @ dadoonet. I have two nodes with one replica and a primary shard. This is for testing only. If the node one fails then replica in second node will act as primary shard. At this time if I do update to the index and later when the node one is up will the changes done in node 2 is going to get updated in node 1 as well ?

Comment: Yes. The old shard will be synch'ed with its primary which is now on node 2